Add external yaml file in yaml header Quarto
I would like to load an external yaml file in the yaml header of a qmd document (Quarto). I tried using !include <.yaml> in my yaml header as described here, but this doesn't seem to work. First I create a yaml file called external_yaml.yaml:
author: Quinten
format: dashboard

Now I created a Quarto document called test_file.qmd like this:
---
!include external_yaml.yaml
title: "Yaml with external yaml"
---

# Tab

This is a test

This returns an error:
ERROR: YAMLError: test_file.qmd:
unknown tag !<!include> at line 3, column 6:
    title: "Yaml with external yaml"
         ^
Did you try to use a '!' in a YAML string? If so, you need to add explicit quotes to your string.

Stack trace:
unknown tag !<!include> at line 3, column 6:
    title: "Yaml with external yaml"
         ^
Did you try to use a '!' in a YAML string? If so, you need to add explicit quotes to your string.
    at generateError (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:10478:12)
    at throwError (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:10481:11)
    at composeNode (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:11348:20)
    at readDocument (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:11411:5)
    at loadDocuments (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:11446:9)
    at load (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:11451:23)
    at parse2 (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:11461:12)
    at parseWithNiceErrors (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:19693:16)
    at readYamlFromMarkdown (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:19624:17)
    at markdownExecutionEngine (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:41167:20)

So I was wondering if anyone knows how we could add an external file in a yaml header of a quarto document?

I'm using R 4.4.0 and Quarto 1.4.537.

Hi Quinten - this doesn't work for me either but my error message is slightly different. Which version of Quarto are you using? I'm on 1.4.268 but the question you linked is very recent. There are newer versions, and Quarto is still adding new features regularly, so upgrading may resolve this. I'm reluctant to test by upgrading myself as occasionally doing so seems to break documents would previously compile.

Hi @SamR, I just added the versions to my question. Thanks!

Given the answer to the other question was accepted, it may be worth trying upgrading to the pre-release 1.5.33.

@SamR, Thanks for the suggestion. I updated to the pre-release. Unfortunately, the error remains the same.
